# How to load website template first and the content comes later

Tags: javascript, css, html, web, preload

here's the sample website:https://www.mapbox.com/plans/ or http://facebook.com/
I'm curious about that how they make the pre-visual of the website with template only and load the content later. All I can imagine is hide all content first and show it after everything loaded. Is that right track? any ideas would be helpful, thanks.

[image: mapbox-screenshot]
It's the first sight when you open the http://www.mapbox.com and after you can see the content.
[image]
That's the transition what i want to know. If using ajax, what about the menu or text at first? Thanks :)

Comment: nothing hidden, just ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are talking about.  they are waiting for fonts, and to avoid a glitch they hide until js says it's ready by putting a class `user-loaded` on the body element.

```
.show-in-loaded { opacity: 0; }
.user-loaded .show-in-loaded { opacity: 1; }
```

then what ever has fonts they hide it by putting `show-in-loaded`.

in some js function indicating ready state they have.

```
$('body').addClass('user-loaded');
```

Comment: cool! I follow your answer and find out the css for the transition and with kindly comment. :)
/* Mask elements before loaded
------------------------------------------------------- */

.show-in-loaded { opacity: 0; }
.user-loaded .show-in-loaded { opacity: 1; }

Comment: I'm not positive, they also have a lot of code to stop impersonation etc.  but fonts are a common reason we see this.    http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6787-font-events here's typekit version.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that loads after the page is loaded has to be an ajax call.

When you send the data from the server, the data gets rendered and the styling is done based on how fast the resources are fetched.

When you request data from an ajax call the data is sent and processed after the page is loaded, however you can also do it sync with page load because it is an async call.

Comment: yeah, so the ajax including the text? I mean during the whole loading i can only see some color blocks like a template and then the text displays immediately. maybe i put on a screenshot to demo the process

Comment: could also be hidden just waiting for the fonts to show up.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this can be a good approach to show text only when all the fonts and images are properly loaded